# Regex to determine whether the image file was downloaded from Facebook

Tags: regex, facebook

Are there published specs for the way Facebook generates its image URLs in the user content?

I see that it's always numeric, has 3 segments made of digits, and ends with `_o`, e.g.:

`13350348_10153901013116284_1057049318676616056_o.jpg`
 `13320779_10153901014316284_6642702744405635433_o.jpg`

I could make a crude attempt, e.g. `[0-9]{8}_[0-9]{17}_[0-9]{19}_o[.]jpg`
But I want to see if there are better ideas out there, as I couldn't find specs or studies. Anyone knows more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the naming scheme is not documented publicly AFAIK also I got a different number of digits in the first two groups:

> 13350348_10153901013116284_1057049318676616056_o.jpg

so I recomment more testing or loosing up the digit count.

also facebook uses `_n` instead of `_o` with profile and cover images.

I found a variable in image urls called "fbid" it sometimes matches the 2nd group of digits but not always.

photo id is mentioned multiple times in the [Facebook Developers website](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/photo-uploads) but not regarding file names, but it doesn't hurt to have look for your self.

I'd suggest a better regex to match out the two filename schemes we know about so far and all supported file formats:

```
\d{6,9}_\d{15,17}_\d{19}_[o|n]\.(jpeg|jpg|bmp|png|gif|tiff)
```

Comment: Thanks, @maher-fattouh! Seems like a comprehensive one.